# Send vibration pattern to a specific android-wear device

Tags: android, wear-os, android-vibration

If I have two android-wear devices connected to my Smartphone, is there a way to send a vibration pattern to only one of the two devices?

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way is to use the Message API; its `sendMessage` method includes a `nodeId` parameter, and by specifying this the message will only get sent to that device. Then on that device, you'll probably subclass `WearableListenerService`, and when you get the message sent from the handheld, use the `Vibrator` class to create the desired pattern.

All of these classes are documented in the official docs at http://developer.android.com.